# Storing time in 24 Hr time-format into database with column type time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, time

I am trying to save time into MySQL  database. I have kept the column type as `time` in database.

From the form I am getting the `$_POST` for time in 24-Hr format.

The value from the form for time is as follows:

```
 $_POST[openTime] = 20:00
```

When I convert the time by using `strtotime()` and `date()` I get the output as:

```
$_POST['openTime'] = date( "h:i:s A", strtotime($_POST['openTime']));
```

Output:

```
$_POST[openTime] => 08:00:00 PM
```

So I have a three part question:

1. Am I doing it in the correct way?
2. Can I store the values of `$_POST` directly into database after the steps I have performed above? If no what processing is needed before I store into the database?

so here after the above changes to `$_POST['openTime']` the value is: `$_POST[openTime] => 08:00:00 PM`

3. Do I need to again convert the values of time that I fetch from database to PHP time object?

Please note that there will database operations based on time as well. For example: "which all places are open after 8PM?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL `TIME` field type has format like `HH:MM:SS`, range from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`. [Read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html). Based on that, you cannot store formated time like `08:00:00 PM`.

If you have posted open time as `20:00`, then you need to use `H:i:s` format:

```php
$_POST['openTime'] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['openTime']));
```

But IMHO this is unnecessary. What you need is a validation, smth like this:

```php
if (preg_match('~^\d{2}:\d{2}$~', $_POST['openTime'])) {
    echo "posted time is valid!";
    $saveTime = $_POST['openTime'] . ':00';
}
```

Comment: I had tried using `H:i:s` but it converts `20:00` to `08:00:00` and not `20:00:00`

Appending `:00` does work.
But i wanted to do with `date()`...so can you help me out with that?

Comment: @ArjunVarrier: then you are posting something different than `20:00`. Show me `var_dump($_POST['openTime']);` and we shall see, because [this code works](https://eval.in/232410).

Comment: the `var_dump($_POST['openTime'])` is `string(5) "14:30"` for the input 2:30PM.
I performed `$_POST['openTime'] = date( "h:i:s", strtotime($_POST['openTime']));` and then echoed out `$_POST['openTime']` the output is `[openTime] => 02:30:00`

Comment: @ArjunVarrier: date format `h` and `H` is different! Please use uppercase for this scenario, like I already said in the answer, and in the [comment demo](https://eval.in/232410).

Comment: Oh extremely sorry...I didn't realize that...
That works
Thanks :)